# XmlTextWriter 'Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace.'

Tags: xml, vb.net

I need to create an XML Node which looks like this:

```xml
<cac:OrderReference>
    <someline>abc</someline>
</cac:OrderReference>
```

And the solution that I found was to use something like this:

```vb
writer.WriteStartElement("cac", "OrderReference", Nothing)
.... some lines 
writer.WriteFullEndElement()
```

However, I kept getting the error

> Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace.

If I change `Nothing` to a dummy data such as "ns", I get the following result.

```xml
<cac:OrderReference xmlns:cac="ns">
```

Also, I am using the WellFormedXmlWriter which does no allow me to use the `:` character.

Comment: Is `cac` defined earlier in your document? What namespace does it refer to?

Comment: What matters is the namespace, not the prefix. If for some reason you want a specific prefix for a certain namespace (there can be no reason for that other than using a non-conforming XML parser), then you need to associate the namespace with that prefix first. If the first time you do that is on an element, then the `xmlns:cac` declaration is going to appear on that element. If you don't like that, declare the `xmlns:cac="ns"` on an earlier element (often the root element is used). A prefix without a namespace means absolutely nothing.

Comment: Also note that the `<cac:OrderReference>` belongs to one namespace, and `<someline>` inside it belongs to another, *unless* there is also a declaration `xmlns="ns"` somewhere before them.

Comment: In C# there is no `Nothing`, rather use `null`.

Comment: @VillageTech There is also a mandatory semicolon after statements in C# which the OP is not using either. That code is valid VB.NET though.

Comment: Ok, so why it is flagged by `c#` tag?

Comment: Oops yes it’s VB.NET. Also I have to follow this format as it is required by PEPPOL standard

Comment: I need <cac:OrderReference> without any namespace, but after switching to WellFormedXmlWriter, I am unable to use semicolon in my values

Comment: If you need `<cac:OrderReference>` without any namespace, that would be `<OrderReference>`. You cannot bind a prefix to an empty namespace.

Comment: @GSerg you are right, there is supposed to be a xmlns:cac at the root element, but it got accidentally replaced by a typo to xmlns:csc. Yourr firrst comment is the answer